# Display grouped data from PoverPivot in Excel using PivotTable

Tags: excel, reporting, grouping, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have a table in PowerPivot that contains UserID, DatabaseID and CorpID.
I need to display a the list of corpID's for the user that have no DatabaseID.
Currently I am doing it by having a filter on the UserID and having DatabaseID as a column and CorpID in the rows section and then having a slicer on the DatabaseID where I picked (blank).

I would like to find a way to display it in a table format like

```
User1 ID Corp1,Corp2,Corp3,Corp4
User2 ID Corp1,Corp2,Corp3,Corp4
```

where Corp Id's are the corps that have blank in the DB for the user.

Is is possible with PivotTable to do that? I can also have a separate table with only userID's in the PowerPivot and link it to the other if that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can drag UserId to Rows,CorpId to Columns and for example COUNT(UserId) on Values. After that you can set the property of pivot table to show empty values and  add Value filter to show only blank values.

Comment: This does not return anything in to the pivot table.
I use filter by clicking on the arrow next to the column labels and selecting blank there